# Having trouble with client/server calculator C++

Tags: c++, server, client, calculator

I'm new to coding and I have to do this client/server calculator for an exam for my university course. 
Unfortunately my professor did explain us quite nothing so I have to do all the work myself.

I already coded the connection part of the programs and it works fine, infact the client can connect to the server.

The problem I'm facing is with the function in the server that should receive integers from the client.
The problem is that whatever number I send from the client, to the server only arrives 0. 
I know that because I'm using cout to display the value after the function.

Server side function:

```
void ricezione_interi(int intero, int csock){
int bytesRecv = recv(csock, &intero, sizeof(int), 0);
if (bytesRecv == -1)
{
    cout << "Connection issue." << endl;
    close(csock);
    exit(1);
}
if (bytesRecv == 0)
{
    cout << "Client disconnected." << endl;
    close(csock);
    exit(1); 
}

return; }
```

Client side code:

```
int bytesSent = send(sock, &intero, sizeof(int), 0); 

    if (bytesSent == -1)
    {
        cerr << "There was a connection issue." << endl;
        break;
    }
    if (bytesSent == 0)
    {
        cout << "Disconnected." << endl; 
        break;
    }
```

What is the problem with this code ? 
Thank is advance for the attention.

Best regards.

Comment: please dont spam tags, this is not c

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Especially it is not clear how you know that the server always receives a `0` when you never inspect the received value

Comment: ...or maybe you expect the parameter you passed to `recezione_interi` to hold the received value after you called that function? If thats the "problem" the code you show is already enough ;) (but still you should add a just a  bit more)

Comment: @user463035818 while yes in theory, very much unlikely in practice. Given the code, it is almost impossible from practical standpoint to get partial read.

Comment: @SergeyA not sure if you maybe misread my comment. OP passes a parameter by value, assigns something to it in the function and (my guess) expects that the argument passed will hold the value that was set in the function

Comment: @user463035818, oh, I see. Yes, I misread, I thought you meant that OP doesn't check for partial reads.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, I would like that the parameter i passed to ricezione_interi to hold the received value but this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Riccardo It doesnt happen because you pass the parameter by value. If you want the function to modify the argument passed to it you need to pass it by reference, basically what I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that whatever number I send from the client, to the
>   server only arrives 0.

Without a MCVE I can only guess what is the problem. So here is my guess...

What your receiver function does is more or less the same as

```
void foo(int x) {
    x = 24;
}
```

When you call it

```
int main() {
    int y = 0;
    foo(y);
    std::cout << y;
}
```

then you will get `0` as output. The reason is that `x` is passed by value. If you want the function to modify its argument you have to pass it by reference:

```
void foo(int& x) {   // note the &
     x = 24;
}
int main() {
    y = 0;
    foo(y);
    std::cout << y;
}
```

This will print `24`.

PS: Please note that this answer is purely based on guessing. I dont know how you know that the value is always `0` and I had to guess. When asking questions about code it is important to include a minimal complete and verifiable example and the expected output along with the actual output in the question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is my first answer.
I know that it's 0 because after the function I'm using cout to display the value.

Comment: @Riccardo no worries. Read the [tour] and the [help], there is plenty of information on how to write a good question

Comment: @Riccardo "after the function I'm using cout to display the value" this should have been part of the code in your question

Comment: I will do as soon as possible. Thank you very much.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much for the help and the patience.